# LaTeX3 Error: The key 'siunitx/per' is unknown and is being ignored

Tags: siunitx

I would like to include a "list of symbols" chapter in my Bachelor Thesis that includes the symbol, the physical unit and a description. Unfortunately I get an error trying the sample from this website: https://mixable.blog/latex-acronym-fuer-formelverzeichnis-mit-einheiten-versehen/

Error: LaTeX3 Error: The key 'siunitx/per' is unknown and is being ignored.

Error: LaTeX3 Error: The key 'siunitx/fraction' is unknown and is being ignored.

I attached a minimal sample that triggers the error on my computer.
Maybe someone knows a solution to this problem?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{acronym}

\newcommand{\acrounit}[1]{
\acroextra{\makebox[18mm][l]{\si[per=frac,fraction=nice]{#1}}}
}

\begin{document}

\section*{Formelverzeichnis}
\begin{acronym}[LONGEST]
  % Allgemein:
  %\acro{KÜRZEL}[ABKÜRZUNG]{\acrounit{SI-EINHEIT}BESCHREIBUNG}
  % Als Beispiele:
  \acro{A}[\ensuremath{A}]{\acrounit{\meter^2}Oberfläche}
  \acro{Rth}[\ensuremath{R_\mathrm{th}}]{ \acrounit{\kelvin\per\watt}Thermischer Widerstand}
  % ...
\end{acronym}


\section{Introduction}

Nutzung der Abkürzung \ac{A}.

\end{document}
```

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: Unrelated: Please never do this: `R_\mathrm{th}` it is a fluke that it actually works, always use `R_{\mathrm{th}}`

Comment: Exactly from where do you have that `\si` should have options `per` and `fraction`? At least with version 3 I needed at last `per-mode=fraction`, and `fraction=nice` does not seem to be supported

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The options `per` and `fraction` were used in v1 of `siunitx`, which had already been replaced by v2 at the point the linked blog post was written. Any version since the release of v2 will work with

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicefrac}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{per-mode = fraction, fraction-function = \nicefrac}
\begin{document}
\si{\metre\squared}
\si{\kelvin\per\watt}
\end{document}
```

although I would strongly urge using v3 names, which are more semantically accurate:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicefrac}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{per-mode = fraction, fraction-command = \nicefrac}
\begin{document}
\unit{\metre\squared}
\unit{\kelvin\per\watt}
\end{document}
```

---

Note that I've changed `\meter^2` to `\metre\squared`: `\metre` reflects the official unit name, whilst `\squared` can be interpreted by `siunitx` in a way that `^2` cannot.

I have included use of `nicefrac` but personally I do not encourage this: there is a reason why standard fractions look the way they do.

Comment: Note I've cut down to the essentials here, but the same ideas apply to the setup in the question